# how can find the chart starts from pipe "|"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on csv format to markdown, and have code something like this

```
document.querySelector("textarea.csv").addEventListener('input',(e) => {
  const convert = e.target.value
      .replaceAll(", ", " | ")
      .replace(/,\n/g, " |\n| ")
      .replace(/, \n/g, " |\n| ")
      .replace(/ \| \n/g, " |\n| ")
      .replace(/^[!\|]/g, "| ")
  
      
      
  console.log(
    convert
  );
  document.querySelector("textarea.markdown").value = "| " + convert;
})
```

But I think I missed the case to cover the line start from not "|", is there any way to check it?

The full code is here: https://codepen.io/dotku/pen/rNzOZLZ?editors=1010

Comment: Have you considered using a csv parsing library like [papa parse](https://www.papaparse.com/demo) then using parsed result to generate markdown? There possible edge cases such as comma in the cell value that are not handled by this regex pattern.

Comment: What is `.replace(/^[!\|]/g, "| ")` meant to do?

Comment: What is the result you need to obtain here?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add `.replace(/\|/g, '')` as the first `replace`? To remove all `|`s? Or is `.replace(/^[!\|]/g, "| ")` malfunctioning as I noted before? Then replace `.replace(/^[!\|]/g, "| ")` with `.replace(/^(?!\|)/gm, "| ")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used your code, it won't work, it seems will catch the line starts with "|" too. I want to catch the line starts none-"|"

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/8QwRwK/1

Comment: Did the suggestion above help?